# Проблемы с запуском Блазор

Tags: blazor

Всем привет, решил изучить новый фреймворк называемый Blazor.

Ничего даже еще не успел сделать, но уже возникают проблемы.

Делаю банальные шаги,

1. запускаю студию
2. создаю пустой блазор проект
3. далее при запуске меня должно просто перекинуть на их шаблон (как и в приложениях через разор).

Но каждый раз запуск приложения срабатывает только со второго раза.

То есть каждый раз после изменения кода, или просто желания запустить и проверить, мне приходится сначала запустить приложение (ничего не будет происходить), затем остановить его, и потом снова запустить, и вот со второго раза все будет работать.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким?

Comment: Какая версия Blazor, и какая версия VS?

Comment: Я не знаю как посмотреть версию, но я скачивал все самое последнее и актуальное

Comment: Если сборка срабатывает со второго раза, это возможно что вы используете VS 15.8 и если вы используете последнюю версию студии 15.9 , то эта проблема там уже решена

Answer (score 0):

три аспекта, на что обратите внимание

1. важно, чтоб совпадали версия Net с Вашим пакетом блазор,

чтоб посмотреть версию Net => Проект=> Property

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. а пакеты нугет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. *** а еще важно, чтоб нужные [`sdk` были установлены](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0) на вашем посту

*** у меня после всей манипуляции также было, то есть вроде запускается, потом надо перезапустить приложение, чтоб сработало, так вот я перезагрузив комп точно присвоила все значения, и норм.✅